# Twitter API app, does not showing pictures or videos

Tags: laravel, api, twitter

I created Twitter API app in Laravel. The application provide very weird layout. I cannot set up profile picture, or picture for tweet. I am getting only text pretty much. 
I spent whole day to figure out, why my APP does not have picture, url or videos. 
I appreciate any suggestions what might be wrong 
[image: api not pulling media]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" 
integrity="sha384- 
UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('/css/app.css')}}">
<title>Nancy's Twitter API App</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1 class="text-info text-center mt-5">Nancy's Tweets Api</h1>

<div class="container">
        <div class="col align-self-center mb-5">
                <form class="well" action="{{route('post.tweet')}}" 
 method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @csrf
                    @if(count($errors) > 0)
                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <div class="alert alert-danger"> {{$error}}</div>
                    @endforeach
                    @endif
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Your Tweet</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="tweet" 
  rows="3"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Upload Filet</label>
                        <input type="file" class="form-control-file" 
 name="images[]" multiple>
                    </div>

                    <div class="from-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-success">Create 
 Tweet</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <h3>Tweets:</h3>
    @if(!empty($data))
        @foreach ($data as $key => $tweet )
            <div class="card text-primary bg-white mb-3" style="max-width: 
  150rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text"><h3>{{$tweet->text}}</h3></p>

                    @if(!empty($tweet->extented_entities->media)){
                        @foreach ($tweet->extented_entities->media as $i)
                            <img src="{{$i->media_url_https}}" 
  style="width:100px;">

        @endforeach}
    @endif
                                <div class="card-header">
                                    <i class="fas fa-heart">{{$tweet- 
   >favorite_count}}</i>
                                    <i class="fas fa-redo"> {{$tweet- 
 >retweet_count}}</i>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    @endforeach
                    @else
                    <p>No Tweets Found</p>
                    @endif
  </div>

 </body>
 </html>


class TwitterController extends Controller
{
//
 public function twitterUserTimeline(){
    $count = 10;
    $format = 'array';


$data = Twitter::getUserTimeline([$count, $format]);
return view('twitter', compact('data'));
}

public function tweet(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, [
      'tweet' => 'required'
    ]);

    $newTweet = ['status' => $request->tweet];

    if(!empty($request->images)){
      foreach($request->images as $key => $value){
        $uploadMedia = Twitter::uploadMedia(['media' => File::get($value- 
  >getRealPath())]);
        if(!empty($uploadMedia)){
          $newTweet['media_ids'][$uploadMedia->media_id_string] = 
   $uploadMedia->media_id_string;
          }
      }
    }

    $twitter = Twitter::postTweet($newTweet);
    return back();
  }


 }
```

Comment: These items are not contained in the tweet message, but as other parameters in the tweet's JSON data. You appear to be trying to use them, but `extented_entities` appears to be a misspelling, among other things.

Comment: @ceejayoz can you get me on correct path,please?

Comment: Spelling `extended` correctly will be your starting point. If that doesn't fix it, start doing `dump($tweet)` and figure out its structure.